# Are temporary files generated while working with pandas data frames

Tags: python, pandas, temporary-files

Until now, I have always used SAS to work with sensitive data. It would be nice to change to Python instead. However, I realize I do not understand how the data is handled during processing in pandas.

While running SAS, one knows exactly where all the temporary files are stored (hence it is easy to keep these in an encrypted container). But what happens when I use pandas data frames? I think I would not even notice, if the data left my computer during processing.

The size of the mere flat files, of which I typically have dozens to merge, are a couple of Gb. Hence I cannot simply rely on the hope, that everything will be kept in the RAM during processing - or can I? I am currently using a desktop with 64 Gb RAM.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a matter of life and death, I would write the data merging function in C. This is the only way to be 100% sure of what happens with the data. The general philosophy of Python is to hide whatever happens "under the hood", this does not seem to fit your particular use case.